# PDFUtil: How to compare 2 pdf file with not same format and highlight the difference

Tags: java, pdf

I want to compare 2 file PDF and now I am using PdfUtil library.
But I have a problem,PdfUtil still works like expected if files have a same format.If not,The result image will highlight everything and I can't see the difference of content between 2 file.
So,How can I compare only content like TEXT_Mode but still get result image with highlight the difference like VISUAL_MODE
Thanks .
This is my simple code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String result ="/Users/abc/Downloads/Test";
        String pdf1 = "/Users/abc/Downloads/pdf1.pdf";
        String pdf2 =  "/Users/abc/Downloads/pdf2.pdf";

        PDFUtil pdfUtil = new PDFUtil();

        pdfUtil.setCompareMode(CompareMode.VISUAL_MODE);
        pdfUtil.highlightPdfDifference(true);
        pdfUtil.setImageDestinationPath(result);
        boolean abc =pdfUtil.compare(pdf1,pdf2);
        System.out.print(abc);


    }
```

Comment: According to the [pdf-util documentation](https://github.com/vinsguru/pdf-util) it does a pixel by pixel comparison for the two files, so you would likely need to figure out a way to first convert your pdf-s into text (which pdfutil can do) and then back to PDF, in the exact same format. Hard to say how consistent that would be, depending on the PDF-s.

Answer (score 0):

You could try https://github.com/lumpchen/xdiff.ncc, a pdf compare tool based on pdfbox.